# Problems of handling XML datatypes with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, db2

Is there any way to include XML datatype in MYSQl 5.1 or we have a newer version with XML datatype given?? like DB2 and MSSQL having XML datatype..

Comment: there isn't, what are you looking for?

Comment: i have to convert a backend built on DB2 using MYSQL i could see that in the database frequently XML datatype was used so iam trying to know if there is some way to handle XML data with MYSQL... thats it!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have an XML datatype.
In DB2 the `XML` datatype is basically a TEXT blob encoded in UTF-8 that validates the XML upon input. You cannot store anything but valid XML in this container.

MySQL does not have this option, so you'll have to use the `TEXT` datatype using a UTF-8 character set.
If you want to check the validness of the input into the field, you can do that in a trigger.

See here for validation code in a trigger (just general validation, not XML related): http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2009/12/validating-mysql-data-entry-with_15.html

In order to do the XML checking you'll have to install a UDF for that.

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_xql/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MySQL_Xml_UDF.aspx

As far as I can tell these libraries do not support XML validation.

If you're a C(++) or Delphi guru, you can write your own UDF, see: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/misc/article.php/c12615